# Powershell determine active ethernet adapter and his MAC

Tags: powershell, ethernet

In Linux I can determine active Eth adapter, using "ip route" command:

```
vasyl@retail-z3-1:~$ ip route get 8.8.8.8
8.8.8.8 via 10.186.0.1 dev ens4  src 1.1.1.1
```

Is there any way to determine which adapter name (and his MAC) used for internet connectivity in PS? Perhaps get-netadapter or something similar.

PS Right now, I'm using this code to extract MAC address from known adapter:

```
$CurrMac = get-netadapter | Where {$_.name -Match "Ethernet 2"}
$CurrMacaddr = $CurrMac.MacAddress.Replace("-", "")
```

And need to determine internet adapter automatically.

UPD1 Lets assume, that I have a host with 2 or more Eth adapters. One used for internet, rest - for internal network or inactive.

Comment: `Get-NetRoute -DestinationPrefix '0.0.0.0/0' | Get-NetAdapter`?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - https://i.imgur.com/my0FBys.png   It returns both adapters. I need ONLY adapter through which internet is established.

Comment: `Get-NetRoute -DestinationPrefix '0.0.0.0/0' | Sort-Object RouteMetric | Select-Object -First 1 | Get-NetAdapter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like ?

```
$adapters = Get-NetAdapter

foreach ($adapter in  $adapters){
    if($adapter.Status -eq "Up" -and $adapter.Name.Contains("Ethernet")){
    Write-Host $adapter.MacAddress 
    }
}
```

But still you can get more MAC addresses ..

Or using `Get-NetRoute -DestinationPrefix '0.0.0.0/0' | Get-NetAdapter`
Then

```
$activeMAC= Get-NetRoute -DestinationPrefix '0.0.0.0/0' | Get-NetAdapter
Write-Host $activeMAC.MacAddress
```

That should return only 1 MAC

Comment: In this way I will only get all connected adapters. But I need particular adapter, which provides internet access. Other adapters may be connected to networks without internet. https://i.imgur.com/jabuKhr.png - It gives me all active adapters

Comment: Once the adapter is connected, anyway if in limited mode- local access, status should be "Up", then the first piece of code will return it..